# Is it possible to change the 'colormap' scale in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colormap

I have 2 matrices. Matrix `A` contains values between 0 and 1 and matrix `B` contains values between 0 and 90. I would like to display an image with a different color for the numbers in each matrix.

When I use the `colormap` function with:

```
figure; colormap(jet); imshow(A);
```

The image displayed has several levels of gray, when I am supposed to have several colors (because I am using `jet`).

When I use the `colormap` function with:

```
figure; colormap(jet); imshow(B);
```

The image displayed is completely white, probably because my values are higher than 64 (which is the max of `jet`).

How can I solve these two problems? I read a lot of tutorials in several forums but I can't find the answer...

Thank you very much for answering my problem!

Comment: `imshow(A,[min max])` or `imshow(A,[])` for auto

Comment: Use something like `jet(256)` if you want more than the default 64 colours

Answer (score 0):

Just normalize the matrix by its max value if the values are more than 1. So for your B matrix try:

```
imshow(B/max(B(:)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the colormap scaling and the number of actual colors within the colormap like so:

```
figure; imshow( A, [0 1], 'Colormap', jet(100) );
figure; imshow( B, [0 100], 'Colormap', jet(100) );
```

The jet(100) indicates 100 unique colors within the colormap to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong function for the task in hand.
`imshow` expects an N by M by 3 array input, of the RGB channels of an image. When you use a 2D matrix the function assumes it's a grayscale image (it's like replicating it to 3 identical matrices to create these three channels - if all the channels in RGB have the same values you get grayscale colors). You [*can* use this function together with a colormap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imshow.html?s_tid=doc_ta#bvmnrxj-10) to get a colored matrix, but there are much more convenient alternatives.

One simple function for getting a colored representation of a matrix is [`imagesc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) or ([`image`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) if you want to scale the values by yourself). This function takes the values in your matrix, and assign them a color from the colormap you choose:

```
A = rand(10);
figure; colormap(jet); imagesc(A);
```

[image: imagesc result]

Another option is [`pcolor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html), which works a little different but give a similar result. `pcolor` attach the values to the vertices of the cells (in oppose to the center, as `imagesc` does), and interpolate the color in each cell from its' vertices. The resulted colored matrix is always smaller in one row and one column because it takes *n+1* points (values in the original matrix) to define *n* gaps (the cells in the colored matrix). Here is an example:

```
A = rand(10);
figure; colormap(jet); pcolor(A);
shading flat
```

[image: pcolor result]